# Where to get Facebook Like and Twitter Follow buttons/widgets?

Tags: facebook-like, twitter-follow

In my user interface page, how to add Facebook likes and Twitter follow button/widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the Facebook like button here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

And you can get the Twitter follow button here:

http://twitter.com/about/resources/followbutton

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like-->http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Twitter follow-->http://twitter.com/about/resources/followbutton